# Concatenate on Google docs gives bad date

Tags: excel, google-sheets, concatenation

I want to fuse 3 items to one using concatenate formula. I am trying to fuse date (2018-06-08) and 2 normal text items (12 and 45). I use this formula `=Concatenate(D2;" ";E2;":";F2)` But when I fuse them, I get 43259 12:45, instead of 2018-06-08 12:45. I tried adding `TEXT` but it only gave me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=D2+time(E2, F2, 0)
```

Format the result as you prefer. e.g. yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. Still wonder why I was getting 43259 though.

Comment: @I'-'I - thanks for stepping in while I was absent. Actually, it is the number of days since 31-Dec-1899 (01-Jan-1900 is 1) but I'm sure that was just a mistype.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(D2,"yyyy-mm-dd"), " ", E2, ":", F2)
```

Because Google docs (like Excel) represents dates with a number (usually it's the number of days since 1900-01-01), you need to convert it to text format with special instructions specifying the order of day, month, year, and what punctuation to separate them.

Currently the documentation for the `TEXT` function can be found [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139).